# How can i remove double coordinates from an array and all coordinates between those double coordinates

Tags: multidimensional-array

I am writing a script to find the path to the exit of a maze and that part works and gives an 2d array with coordinates. But the array contains al coordinates that are tried so i need to remove the coordinates from the array if they are double and all those in between. for example
array = [[3 3], [2 3], [1 3], [2 3], [3 3], [3 4], [3 5]]

final_array = [[3 3], [3 4], [3 5]]

Comment: What language are you using for the script? Also what do you want to do if something appears more times (like [3,3] after the [3,4]) and what happens if, say, [3,4] appears in between two other repeats. E.g.,  [[3 3], [2 3], [3,4], [1 3], [2 3], [3 3], [3 4], [3 5]]

Comment: im using python with the numpy package. I want al double coords deleted and everything in between because if you go straight to the exit of a maze you don't want to come across the same spot